# Hovering after hovering not changing its related div

Tags: jquery, hover

This is to display its associated Div when a user hovers radio buttons but after hovering in and out, the div is not changing, showing the last div when hovering back to the first radio button.

```
In hmtl, 
    <input class="hide" id="test-1" type="radio" name="hello">
    <label for="test-1" class="greetings">Hello</label>
    <div class="content">The first div...</div>

    <input class="hide" id="test-2" type="radio" name="hello">
    <label for="test-2" class="greetings">Hi</label>
    <div class="content">The second div...</div>

In css, 
    .content {
        display: none;
    }

In JQuery, 
    $('.greetings').hover(function() {
        $(this).next('.content').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

It works when it is hovered from first to second, but in reverse, it only shows the second content. How can I fire a fresh trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Tried doing this in which i have to validate if a next() can be triggered. so it goes like this..

```
$('.greetings').hover(function() {
            var checkDiv =  $(this).next('.content');
            if(checkDiv){
        checkDiv.css('display', 'block');
    }else{
      $(this).prev('.content').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

and then used `prev()` if `next()` is not available.
Let me know if it helped you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/okg8nLpm/)

I used `toggle` method to toggles between hide() and show() for the selected elements.

```js
$('.greetingsbox input').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.content').toggle();
});
```

```css
 .greetingsbox{ float: left; width: 48%; }

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="greetingsbox">
      <input class="hide" id="test-1" type="radio" name="hello">
      <label for="test-1" class="greetings">Hello</label>
      <div class="content">The first div...</div>
    </div>
   <div class="greetingsbox">
      <input class="hide" id="test-2" type="radio" name="hi">
      <label for="test-2" class="greetings">Hi</label>
      <div class="content">The second div...</div>
    </div>
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I used index of the class and displayed the linked content with the index. It shows exactly what I expected.

Anyway, thanks all.